# Why is React redirect not working for me?

Tags: reactjs

I have a starter screen with two buttons which are login and register. Here is the code for the same:

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './Header.jsx';
import Authentication from './AuthenticateCard.jsx';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
function StarterScreen() {
  function loginClick()
    {
      return(<Redirect to= "/login" />);
      alert("Tru");
    }
    function registerClick()
    {
      console.log("Register");
    }
  return (
    <div>
      <Header header="My Water Chain"/>
      <div className="WhiteCard">
      <div className="whiteSpace">
      </div>
      <Authentication text="Login" onClickaction={loginClick} />
      <Authentication text="Register" onClickaction={registerClick}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default StarterScreen;
```

Here is my main app.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import StarterScreen from './components/StarterScreen.jsx';
import LoginScreen from './components/LoginScreen.jsx';
import RegisterScreen from './components/RegisterScreen.jsx';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter,Route,Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
function App() {
  function loginClick()
    {
      console.log("Login");
    }
    function registerClick()
    {
      console.log("Register");
    }
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
    <Route component={StarterScreen} exact path="/"></Route>
    <Route component={LoginScreen} exact path="/register"></Route>
    <Route component={StarterScreen} exact path="/login"></Route>
    </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

when I click on login it just freezes and nothing happens afterwards. Screen does respond but no login action takes place with a bunch of errors:
[image]

Comment: `loginClick` seems to just return some JSX. I think what you want is the `useHistory` hook from `react-router-dom`

Comment: It's a function actually. But let me try what you have said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './Header.jsx';
import Authentication from './AuthenticateCard.jsx';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

function StarterScreen(props) {
  function loginClick()
    {
      props.history.push('/login');
    }
    function registerClick()
    {
      console.log("Register");
    }
  return (
    <div>
      <Header header="My Water Chain"/>
      <div className="WhiteCard">
      <div className="whiteSpace">
      </div>
      <Authentication text="Login" onClickaction={loginClick} />
      <Authentication text="Register" onClickaction={registerClick}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withRouter(StarterScreen);
```

Note here, I added `withRouter` to wrap your component and imported it from react-router-dom. Then I'm using `props.history.push` to navigate

Answer (score 1):

You should not return a `Redirect` within event handler in `StarterScreen`, you can take advantage of the `withRoutes` high oder component or using `useHistory` hook to have access to the history of the navigator and change the route by calling `push` with the route where you want to navigate to.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const StarterScreen = ({history}) => {
    const loginClick = () => {
        history.push("/login");
    }
    return <div>
        <Header header="My Water Chain"/>
        <div className="WhiteCard">
            <div className="whiteSpace">
            </div>
            <Authentication text="Login" onClickaction={loginClick} />
            <Authentication text="Register" onClickaction={registerClick}/>
        </div>
    </div>;
}

export default withRouter(StarterScreen);
```

The `withRouter` high order component will pass *3* properties to you component has props `match`, `location` and `history`.

You can learn more here [withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my way to redirect, i created a file call redirect.tsx, and then you can call from other file:

```
import { useHistory, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const Redirect = (props: any) => { 
    const to = (props.to || '/');
    let history = useHistory();
        history.push(to);
        window.location.reload();
    return (
      <>
      </>
     )
   }
export default withRouter(Redirect);
```

Without `window.location.reload();` browser still redirect but it can not show anything!
Good day!